# Passing zoom.scale to a global variable d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I'm rather new to JavaScript, D3, and how scoping works in JavaScript, and am having trouble scaling points on a map (represented as different sized circles) so that as the user zooms, the points stay the same size. To accomplish this, I was thinking of passing the current zoom scale to a global variable, then divide that by the radius of the circles, but am having difficulty passing the value from zoom.scale to a global variable.

Zoom code as follows:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom",function(){
    g.attr("transform","translate("+ 
    d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
        console.log(zoom.scale()); //this works
});
```

Code for circles as follows:

```
d3.csv("cities.csv", function(error, data) { 
//..other code
    g.selectAll("circle")
   .data(data)
   .enter()       
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) {
           return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
   })
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
           return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
   })
   .attr("r", function(d) { return radius(d.pop)/zoomScale; }) //other code...
});
```

Where **zoomScale** is a variable passed from **zoom**. If there is an easier way to accomplish this, I am open to that as well, thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want [semantic zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957) for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I've created a jsfiddle that gives a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/jamiesonmatthew/5ofm4sx0/  Any suggestions for how I could implement semantic zoom in this case?

Comment: In the zoom handler you need to rerun the code that draws the elements with the projection changed according to the zoom.

Comment: I got ya, I've revised my jsfiddle, and its working now: http://jsfiddle.net/5ofm4sx0/2/